# How to count the number of items in a section of the bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing a flutter application for a project of my studies. It is a click and collect application. I would like to add on the icon of the basket, the number of products inside, such as this :

[image: example of icon]

I look a forum on internet but I didn't find anything, I find just a tuto for make a nav bar

Comment: Icon that you added to the question came from Home Screen Launcher On Android counter on Home Screen Launcher is added by launcher based on application notification count. Whether the counter will be added depends on the launcher application.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Badge` Package: [Here](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)
In this package you can add animation and much more...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Badge](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) package.

Add as dependency via terminal

```
flutter pub add badges
```

Import and refer to [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/badges/latest/) for more customization.

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
...
Badge(
  badgeContent: const Text('Hello'),
  child: const Icon(
    Icons.abc
 ),
),
...
```